# Can this be written as a summation?

Tags: summation, notation

As a disclaimer, I'm not asking about the physics behind a formula; I'm purely curious about mathematical notation. That said, I've learned the following formula in physics, representing the electric potential energy when three charges are present:

$$U_E = k(\frac{q_1q_2}{r_{12}} + \frac{q_1q_3}{r_{13}} + \frac{q_2q_3}{r_{23}})$$

Or I suppose if four charges were present, the equation would become:

$$U_E = k(\frac{q_1q_2}{r_{12}} + \frac{q_1q_3}{r_{13}} + \frac{q_1q_4}{r_{14}} + \frac{q_2q_3}{r_{23}} + \frac{q_2q_4}{r_{24}} +  \frac{q_3q_4}{r_{34}})$$

There will be $n \choose 2$ terms summed up for $n$ charges present, if this pattern continues. Essentially, all pairs of charges contribute to the electric potential energy. Can this formula be generalized in a summation? I've thought about this programmatically, where the subscripts of $q$ can be generalized by a nested `for` loop such as in the following pseudo-code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; ++j) {
        print(i, j);
        // prints: 12, 13, 14, ... 23, 24, 25, ... n-1 n
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one :$$U_E=k\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=i+1}^3\frac{q_iq_j}{r_{ij}}=k\sum_{j>i>0}^3\frac{q_iq_j}{r_{ij}}$$
Second one:
$$U_{E}=k\sum_{j>i>0}^4\frac{q_iq_j}{r_{ij}}$$

Note that a common convention that allows this summation to be justified is 
$$\sum_{i=b}^a\text{stuff}=0$$ whenever $b>a$.

Comment: This is a better version of the answer I would have written, so I'll add: The bounds $\displaystyle \sum_{j > i > 0}^3$ tell one to sum over all pairs $(j, i)$ with $3 \ge j > i > 0$; i.e., the pairs $(3, 1), (3, 2), (2, 1)$. I got tripped up with the initial $3 > j$ vs $3 \ge j$, so I thought it was worth mentioning (actually I had just intended to write the "all pairs" part, then missed the $(3, \_\_)$ pairs...)

Comment: Are $i$ and $j$ ever equal using this notation?

Comment: @ArchieGertsman never

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help: $$ \left(\sum_{1< i< j< n} \frac{q_i q_j}{r_{ij}}\right) \times k $$

I simply used this notation to limit $i,\,j$ according to the given problem. It maybe wrong (suggestions are always welcome)

Comment: I suggest that you note that it is better to avoid the use of pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers, please [edit] the post.